# How can it be determined if two cells of equal voltage are connected in parallel?

Tags: voltage

I have an alternator that always charges a car battery, which rests at 12.5V, but sometimes is connected via a latching relay to a large LiFePO4 battery for charging purposes.

In case of system failure, it would be nice to know whether the relay is open or closed. This could easily be achieved by simply measuring the voltage of the two batteries. If they're almost equal, they're connected.

But when the large battery is drained, the voltage may drop from resting voltage of 13.0V to 12.5V. Thus the two batteries have equal voltage, and it cannot be determined by this method whether the relay is open or closed.

Is there another way to determine this?

**Ideas:**

1. One way could be to induce a load on the car battery side, which would cause a change in voltage, but maybe there's a better way?
2. Another way could be to place the latching relay on the ground side, but this would prevent monitoring the car battery voltage. Also, in this specific situation, there must be common ground (chassis, to reduce cabling requirements).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Qs4K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Measure current? Maybe Hall effect?

Comment: You SHOULD NOT connect batteries of different type (chemistrys) in parallel, as they will have different charge/discharge requirements. (And incorrectly charging lithium cells can be ...exciting)

Comment: What type is the 'lithium' battery (eg. Lithium-ion, Lithium-Polymer, LiFePO4)?

Comment: @PeterBennett, In this case, I am using LiFePO4 which has compatible voltage range (charging up to 14.4V for a 4-cell battery)

Comment: @Bradman175, The current will be zero when the voltages are equal, so this approach won't give any additional data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting the state electrically is awkward, as you've described it. Use a latching relay with a second set of contacts and detect from them.

If the latching relay is big and expensive, put the coils of a second smaller-cheaper latching relay in parallel with the coils of your existing latching relay.

Answer (score -1):

Connection of two batteries should usually include an isolator, so that the two do not fight if one has the higher terminal voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpNe7g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

so one way to tell if the switch is closed, is to examine the anode-to-cathode
voltage on that isolator rectifier.   If it is significantly over zero (in
the 0.1 to 1 V range) when the alternator is active, then the switch is closed.

A simpler way is to use a two-pole relay as your switch; the second relay pole can
power a lamp labeled 'connected', or operate any other kind of indicator.

Better, a two-pole relay can be wired to latch only while power is applied,
and will drop back to 'unconnected' whenever power is interrupted.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyrN6g.png)</sup>

Comment: Batteries don't fight if the terminal voltage is different, you simply have balancing currents that flow. In addition the isolating diodes you show prevent both batteries from supplying a load.

Comment: Of course they 'fight' when the switch is closed.  The freshest of the two batteries might deliver 200A to the weaker (or the one with a shorted cell).

Comment: Not even reasonably possible since the terminal voltage of the lower voltage battery will rise rapidly. And it's still not a fight, it's simply one battery charging another.

Comment: But, it's charging with NO CHARGE CURRENT LIMIT.  That's the way you blast a short from a NiCd cell, by connecting a good battery to it.  The second battery in this case is a lithium type, it may tolerate the surge, or it can catch fire.   A lead/acid battery might boil and spray acid.

Comment: The highest voltage battery has the lower output resistance, and the discharged battery a high output resistance.....these very effectively stop your unrealistically high charge rates from happening. Most charging systems regulate the charging current by setting the voltage output from the charger/alternator, they also have an output resistance that causes the voltage to drop if the current is high. While I agree you may see very high current if you short a battery ....connecting a flat battery to a fully charged one is not the same risk.

Comment: Some battery manufactures even recommend connecting a fully charged battery to a flat battery if the terminal voltage is too low to allow a charger to start: http://www.odysseybattery.com/documents/ProceduretorecoverdeeplydischargedODYSSEY.pdf

Comment: In practice (which is what matters), my typical 90Ah car battery, half discharged (e.g. 12.2V), pulls about 10-20A from the fully charged lithium battery (e.g. 13.3V). This tapers off after about 5-10 minutes. As others have mentioned, the lithium battery has both lower internal resistance and a higher voltage level, and therefore provides most of the current for any devices that are connected.